# Is it possible to make Spring MVC not to send an answer back to the client?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am working on a Stub of a microservice with which the Network Function under test communicates via a REST API. The stub is developed with Spring MVC (Spring Boot 2.5.0)

Under certain cirtumstances we need to provoke an absence of reply from the stub to the NF. And here is where the question comes: how to sneak into the Servlet to block the reply back to the client? If that is even possible.

I have been for a while googling but I haven't found anything being really of any use. Before digging more into the framework I am making the question in case someone has had to solve this problem before.

If it is, any hint that we can use to work on the solution would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly - no, you cannot do that. But you can use an external component to achieve that. Google for `envoy fault injection`. Or if you only need skipping a response, then it might be easier to implement it yourself - it's no more than a dozen of lines of Go code.

Comment: Thanks Svetlin. the use of envoy we'd like to avoid unless no other programmatic choice is at hand. The use of Spring makes it impossible to change that, but we need it because other parts of the stub would be tons of boilerplate code, harder to maintain, to achieve the same thing. Thanks for your answer